# Can I use a Fourier transform to solve a higher order PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

Say I had a PDE given by

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial^4u}{\partial x^2} + u = f(x)$$

Can I use Fourier transforms to solve this as I would be able to with a second-order problem?

Comment: You absolutely can if you're looking specifically for $L^1$ or $L^2$ solutions or some such.

Comment: You can address easily any linear constant coefficient PDE.

Comment: How might I approach this using FTs?

Comment: **HINT:** $\mathcal{F}(\mathrm{D}^n f)(\xi)=(2\pi i\xi)^n\mathcal{F}(f)(\xi)$

Comment: Would part of the equation contain the term $k^3$?